# R color points in stripplot

Tags: r, lattice

i created one stripplot in R with lattice package.

stripplot(a~ b, data = df)

Now i want a different colour in a specific point.

Is it possible?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can provide a vector of colors to do this. Here is an example:

```
A<-1:5
B<-6:10
stripplot(A~B,col=c("blue","blue","red","blue","blue"),pch=16,cex=3)
```

[image]